# Allow grid height to change with number of rows (autoheight)

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I'm implementing a grid in ExtJS 7.0.0 (Modern) and would like the height of the grid to be set to the number of rows that it contains. As you can see from the [example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern&profile=material#array-grid) on the ExtJS Kitchen Sink the height of the grid is set to 400 and the grid must be scrolled to see the rest of the rows.

[Screenshot of the grid that must be scrolled to view all the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zclzl.png)

What I am looking for is to be able to set the height to auto and have the grid height adapt to suit the number of rows in the grid. We have found a way to do this in older versions of ExtJS however I can't find a solution to this for version 7 (Modern).

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Take a look at my [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3ae7) if you want to have a go.

Comment: on store load:

GridHeight = HeaderHeight + (recordCount*rowHeight);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3ae4&view/editor)

The key feature is setting grid property scrollable: true

The panel layout is set to vbox.
I set the maxHeight to 400 so the grid will be 400 pixels high but you can not set the maxHeight property and set flex: 1 and the grid will take up all the space vertically that is available and the balance will be scrolltable.

EDIT: [New Fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3aeg&view/editor) Use a vbox layout and set infinite to false on the grid. On your fiddle just remove the height:300 property and add infinite: false

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to have to set a max height.  In your example I need to scroll the grid which is what I am trying to avoid. Take a look at this fiddle and you can see what I mean: https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3ae7

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3aeg&view/editor  Use a vbox layout and set infinite to false on the grid.  On your fiddle just remove the height:300 property and add infinite: false.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. Your second fiddle is exactly what I am after. If you update your answer I'll mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

1. Native way:

```
let grid = Ext.getCmp('example-grid-id'); //get your grid component, there are few ways to do this. "getCmp" is one of those ways
let gridHeightHeader = grid.renderElement.dom.getElementsByClassName("x-headercontainer")[0].offsetHeight;
let gridHeightBody   = 0;
let rows = grid.renderElement.dom.getElementsByClassName("x-listitem");
Array.from(rows).forEach(function(row){
    gridHeightBody+=row.offsetHeight; // in pixel, you can console log here
});
grid.setHeight(gridHeightHeader+gridHeightBody+40); // set new dynamic height of the grid + 40 as additional height
```

2. Sencha Ext JS way:

```
{
    xtype : "panel", //parent of grid component
    fullscreen: true, //optional
    layout:"fit", //HERE is the key
    items:{
        xtype:'grid',
        // height: you don't need this height prop again :)
    }
}
```